# Y a-t-il un mot pour désigner la relation professionnelle entre un patient et son médecin ?

Tags: vocabulaire, travail

Je recherche un mot ou une locution pour désigner la relation entre un membre du corps médical (médecin, thérapeute, infirmier, etc.) et son patient, couvrant implicitement la notion de secret médical.

À l'oral, j'ai tendance à dire « relation patient-médecin ». Et je voudrais l'utiliser dans une telle phrase : « Dans le cadre de notre *relation patient-médecin*, je voudrais vous dire... »

Pour un exemple dans un contexte entre un client et son fournisseur, je dirais « Dans le cadre de notre *relation professionnelle*, je voudrais vous dire... »

Existe-t-il un tel mot ?

Comment: Pas en un seul mot mais "Sous couvert du secret médical, je voudrais vous dire..."

Comment: Cela convient à la phrase mentionnée, mais n'est pas vraiment interchangeable avec « relation patient-médecin ». La référence au secret médical est explicite. C'est véritablement un substantif que je cherche pour une lettre et afin de le réutiliser.

Comment: Pourquoi cherches-tu une locution autre que « relation patient-médecin » ?

Comment: Elle me semble être un raccourci peu correct pour « relation entre un patient et son médecin ». Me trompé-je ?

Comment: J'ai rajouté un terme différent pour un contexte différent : « relation professionnelle » afin de donner une idée plus précise de ce que j'attends.

Comment: Les _rapports_... professionnels ? Ça m'apparaît plus générique que vos solutions.

Comment: Wikipédia s'étand assez longuement sur la "relation médecin-patient" ou "relation patient-médecin". Je ne suis pas sûr qu'il y ait d'autre mot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Colloque Singulier**
Le Colloque Singulier est, dans son acception première, la relation bilatérale et protégée, en confiance, du médecin et de son patient.

(https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloque_singulier)

Comment: Je n'en ai plus besoin en ce moment, mais c'est précisément ce que je cherchais. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

Dans le cadre de cette consultation, je voudrais ...

Answer (score 1):

Une façon fréquente d'exprimer la chose:

> je vous confie ceci **sous le sceau du secret médical**.